# Minecraft went small

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

something happened to my Minecraft . I changed language and when I returned back to English everything came up smaller. I cannot get back to my old normal settings. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that this was caused by you changing the language.

I think you accidently changed the **GUI Scale** setting. Try changing it back to normal.

[image: GUI scale]

Comment: thank you so much we turned the GUI Scale on auto and it worked. thanks again for the help!!!!